# Firebase Valueeventlistener taking so much time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The value event listener works normally at every activity. But in my sign up activity it's taking more than 2 minutes . I don't know why.

This is my method

```
  private void verifyuserinput() {


        System.out.println("Verifying User Input");
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("Verifying Username");

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(username.getText().toString())){
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Username doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Here is my full sign up code
https://pastebin.com/fidvpRLE

The time difference between both prints is 2min+

Also in those two minutes it consumed so much data. Like 1MBps per second for 2 minutes constantly.

Log

```
07-01 21:56:25.315 21504-21504/com.aye.chat I/System.out: Verifying User Input
07-01 21:58:01.960 21504-21504/com.aye.chat I/System.out: Verifying Username
```

There is the time difference.

And the firebase reference only contains usernames as child and next all their infos. SO i just want to check the username exists or not.

And as i said it works everywhere normally except this class.
Please need help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're downloading all data under `userRef` to verify whether this specific user exists. That is wasteful and worse: it will waste more data as you have more users.

To verify is a specific user exists, you should look for a solution that only requires you to read a single user node. From looking at your current code, that could be done with:

```
userRef.child(username.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("Verifying Username");

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Username doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

The above code attaches the listener one level lower in the JSON tree, on precisely the node that you're trying to check. This changes it from the `O(n)` to an `O(1)` operation.

The condition in the code seems inverted: printing that a user doesn't exist when the data shows that it does. But since the same logic was in your snippet, I decided to leave it unmodified.